# Replacing variables in a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, find-and-replace

I have one file called `template.tpl`.

```
#!/bin/bash
RESULT=`curl https://${MY_VAR_USERNAME}:${MY_VAR_PASSWORD}@my-domain.com/service`
echo $RESULT
if [ "$RESULT" == "ok" ]; then
  exit 0
fi
exit 2
```

this template file should be parsed with this script `replace-script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -a
: ${MY_VAR_USERNAME="testuser"}
: ${MY_VAR_PASSWORD="supersecurepassword"}
# replace every variable declared in a .tpl file delete the .tpl extention 
srcFile="template.tpl"
cat $srcFile | envsubst > $(echo $srcFile | sed -r 's/.tpl$//')
```

When i make now a `bash replace-script.sh` I got the following result:

```
#!/bin/bash
RESULT=`curl https://testuser:supersecurepassword@my-domain.com/service`
echo 
if [ "" == "ok" ]; then
  exit 0
fi
exit 2
```

so, the variable I want to be parsed are perfectly parsed. But the bad thing is, that EVERY $VAR is replaced, not only the ones declared in my `replace-script.sh` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`envsubst` can take a list of the arguments to substitute:

```
envsubst '$MY_VAR_USERNAME $MY_VAR_PASSWORD'
```

(They must be in a single string, they must have the `$` signs, annoyingly.)

---

Note that the standard string comparison operator is `=`, not `==`, the latter works in Bash and maybe others, but not in `dash` (Debian and Ubuntu's `/bin/sh`)

Also, you can skip the sed and use the shell's expansions to remove the suffix from the file name: `"${srcFile%.tpl}"`

Comment: this helped me a lot, but is there any change NOT to write every single variable twice, but to use the already in this file defined variables?

Because normally I have more than this 2 variables, so I don't want to write all of them twice

I use 
`cat $srcFile | envsubst '$MY_VAR_USERNAME $MY_VAR_PASSWORD $MY_VAR_USERNAME2 $MY_VAR_PASSWORD2 $MY_VAR_USERNAME3 $MY_VAR_PASSWORD3' > "${srcFile%.tpl}" `

Comment: @Joerg, hmh. With numbered names like that I'd like to generate the list of them programmatically. `s=; for x in 1 2 3; do s+="\$MY_VAR_USERNAME$x " ; done` comes to mind, not that it's much shorter than just listing them out. And there's no good way to unexport everything from the shell (losing `PATH` and `HOME` would probably break many programs anyway). If I had to something like that myself, I'd probably start writing a Perl script to replace `envsubst` with...

Comment: no, they are not really numbered, that's just for demonstration, no naming convention..  and sorry, I'm not into Perl at all (yet).